# Fan runs at max when screen is dimmed to save power

Tags: 12.04, fan, vaio

Everytime the screen dims to save power after my laptop has been idle, the fan starts spinning really fast and the cpu temp rises to about 60 deg C. When I move the mouse to undim the screen, the fan returns back to normal.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on Sony VAIO laptop

Comment: This seems to be a bug. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) how to post a bug report

Comment: I'm too lazy to report a bug

Comment: Then im too sorry, no one else can help you.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the time/skill to debug this, simply turn off screen dimming from "Brightness and Lock" in System Settings:

[image]